# How to have a popup with a field where I can take email id as input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on implementing "invite someone" functionality on a webapp. I have a "invite" button. Now I want that whenever someone clicks on it, a popup should apear on screen asking for an email id as input, which I can use to send an invite link. So I am not sure how to have that popup with an input field.

Apologies if someone find this question too basic. I am pretty new to react.js

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the open and close state of your popup with the component state. You can either use css or Javascript to show or hide the popup.

If you use CSS you need to pass a css class to the popup like so:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    open: false
  }

  handlePopUp(){
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <button onClick={() => this.handlePopUp()}>Open / close</button>

        <div className={`modal ${this.state.oepn}`}>
          {/* form content here */}
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you are using Javascript you will need to have a conditional like so:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    open: false
  }

  handlePopUp(){
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <button onClick={() => this.handlePopUp()}>Open / close</button>

        {
          this.state.oepn ?
            <div className="modal">
              {/* form content here */}
            </div> 
            : null
        }


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I would recommend handling it with CSS so you can do some nice css transitions

Comment: ..How can I create that popup with input field that I can catch for later use? That will be a great help

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking